# Finder Isn't Responding Mac 10.10.1

Tags: macos

I am having a problem "Finder isn't responding" on my mac pro retina 10.10.1. All my files on my desktop are gone and the rainbow ball is spinning forever. I've tried many times to relaunch "Finder" by using command + option + esc, yet the problem still exist. So anyone has any idea to fix this problem? Please kindly help.

Comment: will be soon with you. meanwhile did you try restart, or log in as different user or start in safe mode, all actions that would allow finder the heal.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I have tried to restart many time as well, but it didn't work at all. Please kindly help.

Comment: In my case, the cause of this problem is very stupid. My girlfriends has put six thousands of screenshots in desktop when she is watching videos. I even don't notice this until tried deleting *.plist and restart. Just put those screenshots inside one folder solved it. Hope this somehow help. I'm guessing finder is working to hard to maintain thumbnails and arrange the views.

Answer (score -1):

Please upgrade your OS to OSX EI Capitan which is the latest version of Mac OS X and possibly fixed many bugs of Yosemite and works really fast has inbuilt memory optimizer tool to free up RAM.